# Is Calendly creating a seperate page for every user calendar in React or is it something else

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, rest, frontend

I am building a [Calendly](https://calendly.com) clone and I have figured out pretty much everything.
But only thing I am stuck at is how they are rendering my [calendar page](https://calendly.com/hateyoh588/30min?month=2022-06).
[image]

If you load this page, left side of the component is static and right side is rendered from server. And I know this because I have combed through the response of every network request from the devtools and I have not found any response that matches the data in the left side.

**So my question is are they creating a seperate page for every user calendar or is it something else**.

Comment: "I have combed through the response of every network request from the devtools and I have not found any response that matches the data in the left side." -- the data _is_ in there _somewhere_. It might be in a server-rendered page; it might be in an AJAX response; it might be cached from earlier. But it _must_ have been sent from the server to the browser at some point.

Comment: What is the practical purpose of this for your own clone? Just a curiosity? You can check page source code, it's evident that some data is provided on server side for hydration instead of being fetched, `window.BackendData =`

Comment: Thanks @EstusFlask I think you are onto something and I am building this to improve my skills and also it will be a good addition to my portfolio

Comment: Hi, why is this one tagged as Vue **and** React here?

Comment: @kissu because I am creating its frontend in vue and Calendly has built it in react. And also it is a frontend issue and these both frameworks are for frontend

Comment: At the end, this question is framework agnostic since it doesn't even have a code. I would have tagged it as [tag:javascript] and that's all. It's not relevant to people watching Vue/React tags IMO, especially since you already have [tag:frontend]

Comment: Hey @kissu I think you are right. Next time I'll keep it in mind